# Preserve nested list structure with itemgetter in Python

Tags: python, list

As an example, suppose `a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 5]]`, and `inds` is a list of indices of `a` whose entries I would like to extract. For instance,

```
In [1]: from operator import itemgetter

In [2]: itemgetter(*inds)(a)
Out[2]: ([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4])
```

which works fine. However, if `inds` contains only one element, then the result is no longer a tuple of (sub-)lists:

```
In [3]: itemgetter(*[0])(a)
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a way to make `itemgetter` still return the same format: `([1, 2, 3])` in this case? I need the output format to have the same level of depth for latter processing regardless of the number of elements it contains.

Comment: A workaround: `res = itemgetter(*inds)(a)`. ->   `if isinstance(res, list):` -> `res = (res,)`